# assign value to a list inside another list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please check the code bellow. I am just simply trying to assign value to `List<ThirdPartyData>` which lives inside another class called `GetFiftyItemsData` but the way i am trying to do it it says syntax error. Please check `itemLists.Add()` part whats wrong i am doing here?

**C# Code**:

```
var itemLists = new List<GetFiftyItemsData>();

itemLists.Add(new GetFiftyItemsData
                            {
                                SellerId = sellerId,

                            }.ThirdPartyData.Add(new ThirdPartyData {



                            }));
```

**Model class:**

```
  class GetFiftyItemsData
    {
        public long SellerId { get; set; }
        public List<ThirdPartyData> ThirdPartyData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: well definition of Add is `void List<T>.Add(T)` not `T List<T>.Add(T)` edit: your code is even more f u ... please, follow some basic tutorials about C# language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
itemLists.Add(new GetFiftyItemsData
        {
            SellerId = sellerId,
            ThirdPartyData = new List<ThirdPartyData> {
                // item,
                // item
            })
        });
```

And it's better not to name your field/property and type the same (ThirdPartyData).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could declare variable step by step, let it be more readable, new ThirdPartyData first, then assign to GetFiftyItemsData, and add to itemLists.

```cs
long sellerId = 1;
List<ThirdPartyData> ThirdPartyData = new List<ThirdPartyData>();
ThirdPartyData.Add(new ThirdPartyData() { });

itemLists.Add(new GetFiftyItemsData
{
    SellerId = sellerId,
    ThirdPartyData = ThirdPartyData
});
```